# Can you add a summary after edit?

Tags: support, edits, edit-summary

I just made an edit to a question I asked. Quite often I don't write summaries, but this time I felt that I should have added some explanation to the edit.

Is there a way to add a summary afterwards? I know that I can do a rollback and a new edit and such things, but I don't think the summary is worth polluting the edit history. I simply want to add a summary to an existing edit.

Comment: Suggested dupe is the dupe-target of [How can I add explanations to previous edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262040/398063) (among others). Basically: you can properly add them during grace period (5 minutes unless someone comments in that span); afterwards it's not possible and as you said it makes the edit history a bit blurry (and might bump it for "nothing"). Leave a comment instead :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're still in the 5-minute 'grace period', you can resubmit the edit with a proper summary. Otherwise, it's not really possible.

But if the edit summary is really important to have, maybe it can even be a part of the post you're editing? The edit summary will only be seen by people actively looking for it.

If you fear the author of the post might rollback your edit because they don't understand it, you could consider leaving a comment (and delete it once you think it has been read - it doesn't really help improving the post afterwards).

Comment: No, please no, not part of the post itself. [Meta information](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuRlLjd3700&t=303) can instead be put in comments.

Comment: I'm not sure if the case the OP is referring to is meta information, why would it be so important to them to mention in the edit summary? Of course, we can't tell without a concrete example.